# Print unmatched patterns, using grep with patterns from file

Tags: grep

patterns.txt:

```
"BananaOpinion"
"ExitWarning"
"SomeMessage"
"Help"
"Introduction"
"MessageToUser"
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="Introduction">One day there was an apple that went to the market.</string>
<string name="BananaOpinion">Bananas are great!</string>
<string name="MessageToUser">We would like to give you apples, bananas and tomatoes.</string>
```

Expected output:

```
"ExitWarning"
"SomeMessage"
"Help"
```

How do I print the terms in `patterns.txt` that are not found in `Strings.xml`? I can print the matched/unmatched *lines* in `Strings.xml`, but how do I print the unmatched *patterns*? I'm using ggrep (GNU grep) version 2.21, but am open to other tools. Apologies if this is a duplicate of another question that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use `grep -o` to print only the matching part and use the result as patterns for a second `grep -v` on the original `patterns.txt` file:

```
grep -oFf patterns.txt Strings.xml | grep -vFf - patterns.txt
```

Though in this particular case you could also use `join` + `sort`:

```
join -t\" -v1 -j2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 <(sort -t\" -k2 patterns.txt) <(sort -t\" -k2 strings.xml)
```

Comment: this is quite elegant.. smart!

Comment: If you have multiple input files (e.g. `Strings1.xml` and `Strings2.xml`), you will also need the `-h` flag on the first grep.

Comment: @jayhendren - yeah but not all `grep`s support that option. If you have multiple input files I don't see why you couldn't simply `cat` them all and pipe the result to `grep`.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is probably what @don_crissti suggested, so here's a variation on the same theme:

```
$ grep -vf <(grep -Po 'name=\K.+?"' Strings.xml) patterns.txt
"ExitWarning"
"SomeMessage"
"Help"
```

This basically is the inverse of @don_crissti's approach. It uses grep with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`) and the `-o` switch to print only the matching part of the line. Then, the regex looks for `name=` and discards it (`\K`), and then looks for one or more characters until the first `"` (`.+?"`). This results in the list of patterns present in the `String.txt` file which is then passed as input to a reverse grep (`grep -v`) using [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`<(command)`).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `cut`, probably. That is, if, as it appears, you know where to expect the quoted string you're looking for.

If I do:

```sh
{   cut  -sd\" -f2 |
    grep -vFf- pat
}   <<\IN
#   <string name="Introduction">One day there was an apple that went to the market.</string>
#   <string name="BananaOpinion">Bananas are great!</string>
#   <string name="MessageToUser">We would like to give you apples, bananas and tomatoes.</string>
IN
```

...after saving my own copy of your example `patterns.txt` in `pat` and running the above command the output is:

```
"ExitWarning"
"SomeMessage"
"Help"
```

`cut` prints to stdout only the second `"` double-quote `-d`elimited `-f`ield for each delimiter-matched line of input and `-s`uppresses all others.

What `cut` actually prints at `grep` is:

```
Introduction
BananaOpinion
MessageToUser
```

`grep` searches its named file operand for lines which `-v` don't match the `-F`ixed strings in its `-` stdin pattern `-f`ile.

If you can rely on the second `"`-delimited field as the one to match, then it will definitely be an optimization over `grep` `-P`erl mode by just matching `-F`ixed strings and only tiny portions of them because `cut` does the heavy lifting - and it does it *fast*.

Answer (score 2):

```
for p in $(cat patterns.txt); do if ! grep $p strings.xml &>/dev/null; then echo $p; fi; done
```

it's easy to understand but has the downtime of spawning multiple grep processes, one for each line in patterns.txt.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to put patterns.txt and Strings.xml into one list and find unique rows

```
cat patterns.txt Strings.xml | grep -oFf patterns.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

explanation:

`cat patterns.txt Strings.xml` puts everything into one list.
`grep -oFf patterns.txt` removes garbage on each line.
`sort` self-explanatory. sort all lines.
`uniq -u` prints only unique lines.